# Declare CSS style outside the "HEAD" element of an "HTML" page?

Tags: html, css, templates, template-engine

my use-case is the following :

I'm composing an **HTML page** by using parts that are **valid HTML fragments** but not valid pages,
like **Divs**; these elements are using **CSS** to manage their style.

I'd like to allow each fragment to be responsible for its own styling requirements and to not rely on the declarations of style-sheets in the main fragment (the one with the "HTML" tag).

So here come the question : **is there any (standard) way to add some CSS styling outside the HEAD element** (excluding the inline styling via the "style" attribute) ?

I guess I could use frames but I'd prefer to avoid this solution.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**FINAL EDIT :**

Thanks to the propositions of ***zzzzBov***, ***JMC Creative*** and ***moontear***, and after some testing, here is the answer :

- use **JavaScript to dynamically load some CSS style-sheets** : **HTML4/XHTML** and **HTML5 compliant**,
- **embed "style" elements** directly inside the fragments : **non-compliant** with **HTML4/XHTML** but seems to be **broadly supported**, and is **HTML5 compliant**.

As I must support email clients I've used the second solution which moreover is more simple.

Comment: could you use javascript to add `<style>` elements to the head, after the fact?

Comment: @JMC Creative : thanks, this should be the best solution indeed but I'm sending mail messages so I cannot rely on JS.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

## tl;dr:

If you're not comfortable using HTML features that haven't reached a maturity level of [W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/2017/Process-20170301/#RecsW3C), there isn't a standard way of adding `<style>` to the `<body>` of a page.

If you're comfortable using less mature features, HTML5.2 appears to be standardizing `<style>` elements to be allowed anywhere flow content is expected (i.e. the `<body>` and most of its elements).

If you're already using the `[scoped]` attribute, stop using the `[scoped]` attribute, as it was never standardized and is losing browser support.

## History:

### HTML 4.01

In HTML4.01 the style element was allowed in the `<head>` only. Browsers, being diligent about attempting to render what the author *wants* rather than what the author *wrote* have respected `<style>` elements in the `<body>` despite those pages technically being invalid.

### HTML 5

The `<style>` element continued to be invalid in the `<body>`

### HTML 5.1

In some [working drafts of the HTML5.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-html51-20160503/document-metadata.html#the-style-element) the `<style>` element was to allow for a `[scoped]` attribute, which would allow the `<style>` element to be used in [flow content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-html51-20160503/dom.html#flow-content) (i.e. in the `<body>`).

As an example of how that could have been used would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Example of using the scoped attribute</title>
<div>
  <style scoped>
    p {
      color: darkred;
    }
  </style>
  <p>this text would be dark red</p>
</div>
<p>this text would be black</p>
```

[Support for the scoped feature was added to Firefox in version 21 and added in Chrome behind a flag in version 20](http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped). The feature didn't receive enough support, so it was later removed from the [HTML5.1 working draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-html51-20160602/document-metadata.html#the-style-element).

[Chrome was first to remove the feature in version 36](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5374137958662144). Firefox has since set the feature to be behind a flag in version 55.

### HTML 5.2

In the [July 2017 working draft of the HTML5.2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/WD-html52-20170718/document-metadata.html#the-style-element), support was added for the `<style>` element to be allowed in flow content:

> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>
> - Where metadata content is expected.
> - In a `<noscript>` element that is a child of a `<head>` element.
> - **In the body, where flow content is expected.**

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

At the time of writing this addition has remained in the HTML5.2 spec, which is currently at the [Candidate Recommendation maturity level](https://www.w3.org/2017/Process-20170301/#maturity-levels).

While this makes using `<style>` elements in the `<body>` still somewhat of a risk, this particular change is standardizing something that browsers have supported for many years.

Comment: HTML5.2 has since reached W3C Recommendation level. I will hopefully update this post when I have some spare time.

Answer (score 13):

There is no **standard** way (**EDIT:** as of HTML5 there apparently is!) of adding a `<style>` element outside of the `<head>` tag - it is only allowed there and NOT within the `<body>` tag ([See the DTD here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-strict.dtd_head.misc)).

If you want to style your HTML fragments individually and not use CSS styles in your head, you will need to resort to inline styling. However: Most browsers understand `<style>` tags within the body, so you may as well use them, but your page won't be standards compliant.

In any way:

- You should not use inline styling
- You should adhere to standards
- You should put the CSS in the head where it belongs

From what I understand you use some kind of templating, where you insert different HTML snippets into the page with different designs. Is it so bad if you put all styles within one big CSS file?

Would it be impossible for you to dynamically load a another CSS file (via JS or server side scripting), when your HTML fragment gets inserted in the page (this would be the preferred method)?

Comment: This is true, however `<style>@import url('path/to/file.css')</style>` within the body tag works in most modern browsers. I know that *disobeying* the rigid requirements of the *holy* W3C is frowned upon, but c'mon, the web is evolving fast, and their standards aren't. Example of it being used by a popular third party service successfully: **ZenDesk.com button code** ... successfully serving an unknown-high-number of requests daily.

Comment: @moontear : Thanks for this clear answer. "you use some kind of templating" : good guess this is exactly my situation. "put all styles within one big CSS file" : if I wasn't sending some of the html pages by email indeed that could be a solution. "dynamically load a another CSS file (via JS or server side scripting)" : really good solution in the general case but I won't be able to use JS inside mail clients too. "Most browsers understand <style> tags within the body" : well, I guess this is the only viable solution in my case.

Comment: @moontear you're correct insofar as HTML4+XHTML1, but the HTML5 **standard** (alright it's not finalized yet, but it's being supported anyway) does define a way to use `style` tags within the `body` of an HTML page.

Comment: @DSKVR : thanks for this trick, it seems to be the perfect solution.

Comment: @zzzzBov : thanks a lot for this info that will make me feel less guilty ;)

Comment: @zzzzBov : Thanks for this update, hard to keep up sometimes :)

Comment: You make it sound as if inline styling is inherently evil and wrong and not standards compliant.  Bad.  Sure, styling in the head or via link has many advantages, and sure, we wish the scoped attribute was supported and backwards compatible, and sure, I would try to redesign my system so this issue wasn't an issue, but there is nothing wrong with using inline styling, especially if I have no better choices.

Comment: Sure thing. Inline styling is fine which is why i wrote "should" not use instead of "must" not use. For example emails will usually look better cross-client when being styled inline.

Answer (score 13):

I've found two *hacks* to do that. Both of which should be perfectly valid html.

### The SVG way

Wrap your `<style />` element inside a `<svg />` element.

```html
<div class="foo">Red text</div>
<svg><style>.foo { color: red }</style></svg>
```

### The Data-Uri Link

Format your css as a data uri and use that in a `<link />` element.

```html
<div class="foo">Red text</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="data:text/css,.foo%20%7B%20color%3A%20red%20%7D" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Is it supported by most browsers?

Comment: Data uri _should_ work in IE8+ ([caniuse#datauri](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri)), SVG _should_ work in IE9+ ([caniuse#svg-html5](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html5))

Comment: OK interesting, you get my +1. :)

Comment: eBay no longer lets you link to external styles. However, I was able to add the data uri solution. Thanks for the info.