# Is adding CSS rules outside the Header possible?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Declare CSS style outside the “HEAD” element of an “HTML” page ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606708/declare-css-style-outside-the-head-element-of-an-html-page)

I am creating some content that is being used inside a CMS where I do not have access to the header tag. Is there a way to add CSS rules within the `<BODY>` of the document?

I want to do this ...

```
.ClassName
{
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

I could add the style rules "inline" inside the element but I wanted to avoid this if possible since the CSS rules will be used in many elements.

I want to avoid this ...

```
<div style="border: 2px solid red; margin: 5px; padding: 5px">content</div>
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362039/style-and-script-tags-in-html-body-why-not#1362192

Comment: Every serious CMS gives you some way to insert data in the <head> tag. What CMS are you using ? There could be a specific answer to your problem, that could lead to a valid page too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `<style>` inside `body`, but you'll [get a validation error](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Foduxez&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0):

> Element style not allowed as child of element body in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

*(This is because it's not allowed according to the specs, see [@Oded's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251734/is-adding-css-rules-outside-the-header-possible/5251829#5251829))*

**It works just fine in browsers though.** [Browsers do not care:](http://jsbin.com/oduxez)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<style type="text/css">
.ClassName
{
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>

<div class="ClassName">content</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use a `<style>` element.

```
<style type="text/css" scoped>
.redOutline {
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>

<div class="redOutline">content</div>
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I added to the specifics.

Comment: @Patrick Fisher, it's not true unless you specify the version of HTML.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think having a `<style>` element within the `<body>` is valid for *any* commonly used doctype.

Comment: It is broadly supported by browsers and is HTML5 compliant.

Comment: @thirtydot, read my answer in the duplicate, [it's valid for HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/semantics.html#the-style-element).

Comment: @zzzzBov: Nice, I wasn't aware of that. Looks a bit annoying to use though (can only style elements within the parent element of the `<style>`). I'd probably rather stick it all in one `<style>` element and have a validation warning.

Comment: Apparently, the `scoped` attribute is required for strict compliance with the HTML5 spec, and it must be placed before all flow content within that scope.

Comment: @zzzzBov - Where would you need to define the docType? Keep in mind I do not have access to the header as I am contained within a CMS.

Comment: @webworm doctype needs to go before the header. You'd need to make sure that your Theme/View/Style for the CMS uses HTML5 (`<!DOCTYPE HTML>`), otherwise you'll be forced to use inline styles, scripts or invalid markup.

Comment: Invalid markup isn't the end of the world, though. What really matters is browser support. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.google.com

Comment: This should be the checked answer

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid HTML, according to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3).

In the DTD, the `STYLE` element appears like this:

```
<!ENTITY % head.misc "SCRIPT|STYLE|META|LINK|OBJECT" -- repeatable head elements -->
```

Where the `head.misc` only appears as pard of `HEAD` or `TITLE`.

---

However, as others have noted, many browsers will still parse and use stylesheets that have been defined within the body tags. Your mileage may vary... in particular if you do use a DOCTYPE in your markup.

Answer (score 2):

[Answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362039/style-and-script-tags-in-html-body-why-not#1362192) :)

But in short, they are invalid but many sites add them to the body, especially those built by (bad) Content Management Systems.